# Finding angle ABC problem

Tags: triangles, problem-solving

[image]

I found the above problem on Instagram. I've looked at the problem a few times and I can't think of where to start. How do we find the value of angle ABC. I suspect the solution involves using the sine rule but I don't k ow where to use it. Could someone please give me a hint to solving this problem?

Comment: I posted (and solved) this exact problem that has been linked. Please refer to that instead